# Check If indexes are different in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare indexes in one array, if all indexes are not the same then It should dispay error. If they are same, take one value as string.

First I retrieve data from db,

```
$idNaloga = array();

 while($r=$ss->fetch()){
   $idNaloga[] = $r['idNaloga'];
 }
```

If I receive array like this, it should display error because of 72

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "72"
}
```

If result is, it should take 19 as string.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "19"
}
```

I was trying to use array_unique() function, but could not get correct result. I was googling but could not find it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php --- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php --- Too many ways to do this; what did you try?

Comment: *"I was trying to use array_unique() function, but could not get correct result. I was googling but could not find it."* - You should have included that in the question.

Comment: that does not solve his 72 need to be changed to 19 problem

Comment: for that he would need to do a $key=>$val loop

Comment: You're going in the right direction with `array_unique` - what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with array_unique

```
if (count(array_unique($idNaloga)) > 1) {
     //return error
} else {
    echo $idNaloga[0];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that should work to show the value if it is unique.

Comment: I do prefer `reset($array)` over `$array[0]`. never know, when you get the brilliant idea to actually construct specific keys and `0` then gives you an indexing error ;o/

Comment: Thank you. Correct

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `array_unique` should have worked. Just count its result. If it has more than one entry, then show the error.

```
if (count(array_unique($your_array)) > 1) {
    echo  'error: multiple values';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I interpreted your array correctly, you can make a function that simply counts the number of unique values and either errors or returns the unique value.

```
$a = array( 0 => "19", 1 => "19", 2 => "72" );

$b = array(0 => "19", 1 => "19",2 => "19", 3 => "19");

function checkUniqueValues($arr) {
    $vars = array_unique($arr);
    if (count($vars) > 1) {
         echo "error!";   
    } else {
         // use a return if you want
         echo $vars[0];
    }
}

checkUniqueValues($a);
echo "<br />";
checkUniqueValues($b);
```

Comment: there is no need for defining the index `0 => "19", 1 => "19",...` as this is no associative array

Comment: Been a while since I've written PHP, thanks for the pointer @bub

Answer (score 0):

Here is the different cases tested in php fiddle website. You can pick the code which matches your requirement.

```
<?php

$a = ["19", "19", "19" ];

$b = ["19", "19", "19" ];

$c = ["19", "19", "19", "19"];

$d = ["19","19", "72"];
//method 1
if($a == $b){
    echo "Array a and b are equal";
    echo "<br>";
}else{
     echo "Array a and b are not equal";
    echo "<br>";
}

if($a == $c){
    echo "Array a and c are equal";
    echo "<br>";
}else{
     echo "Array a and c are not equal";
    echo "<br>";
}

if($a == $d){
    echo "Array a and d are equal";
    echo "<br>";
}else{
     echo "Array a and d are not equal";
    echo "<br>";
}

//method 2
array_multisort($a);
    array_multisort($b);
array_multisort($c);
    array_multisort($d);
if(serialize($a) === serialize($b)){
    echo "key matches with values for b";
     echo "<br>";
}
else{
 echo "key doesnt matches with values for b";
     echo "<br>";
}
if(serialize($a) === serialize($c)){
    echo "key matches with values  for c";
     echo "<br>";
}
else{
 echo "key doesnt matches with values for c";
     echo "<br>";
}
if(serialize($a) === serialize($d)){
    echo "key matches with values  for d";
     echo "<br>";
}
else{
 echo "key doesnt matches with values for d";
     echo "<br>";
}


//method 3 (if count doesnt match)
echo "<br>";
$max_count_between_a_and_c = count($a)>count($c)?count($a):count($c);

$error = false;
for($i = 0; $i < $max_count_between_a_and_c; $i++){
    if(isset($a[$i]) && isset($c[$i]) && $a[$i] != $c[$i]) 
        $error =  true;
}
if($error)
       echo "array a and array c are not equal";
else
       echo "array a and array c are equal";

echo "<br>";

$max_count_between_a_and_d = count($a)>count($d)?count($a):count($d);
$error = false;
for($i = 0; $i < $max_count_between_a_and_d; $i++){
    if(isset($a[$i]) && isset($d[$i]) && $a[$i] != $d[$i])
        $error =  true;
}
if($error)
       echo "array a and array d are not equal";
else
       echo "array a and array d are equal";





?>
```

**Output**

```
Array a and b are equal
Array a and c are not equal
Array a and d are not equal
key matches with values for b
key doesnt matches with values for c
key doesnt matches with values for d

array a and array c are equal
array a and array d are not equal
```